# dynamically updating HTML content of Sencha Touch Carousel items?

Tags: dynamic, sencha-touch, carousel

How do I update the HTML content of a Sench Touch Carousel item ?
I'm trying something like this and it is having no effect:

```
item = carousel.getActiveItem();
item.html = "...new html string ...";
carousel.doComponentLayout();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

After much experimentation, found that changing `item.html = "...";` to `item.update( "..." );` does the trick.